# Objective-C - why the button is not aligned bottom center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, autolayout

[image]

I have the button which is not aligned bottom center? Set to full screen:

[image]

Set to bottom center with auto layout:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  int startHeight = 167;
  int frameHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - startHeight;
  [but setFrame:CGRectMake(0, startHeight, 320, frameHeight)];
  [but setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [but setExclusiveTouch:YES];
  [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.view addSubview:but];


  NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"but" : but};
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-167-[but]-0-|"
                                                                    options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[but]-0-|"
                                                                    options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
}


-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender {
  NSLog(@"you clicked on button %@", sender.tag);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[but]-0-|"
options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
```

use

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: but, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
```

**EDIT**

Realized OP's code is Objective - C

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:but attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

**EDIT**

This is the code I have in my ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *but = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [but setTitle:@"ABCD" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [but setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    int startHeight = 167;
    int frameHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - startHeight;
    [but setFrame:CGRectMake(0, startHeight, 320, frameHeight)];
    
    [but setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
    [self.view addSubview:but];
    NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"button" : but};
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button]-0-|"
                                                                      options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:but attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    constraint.active = true;
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

And this is the output :)

[image]

Works like a charm :) Please check what statement are u missing ??

**Mistakes in your code :**

1. You missed "`[but setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];`"

When you are applying auto layout constraint you inform iOS not convert the default autoresizing masks to auto layout constraints as it might conflict with your applied auto layout constraints :)

2.`constraint.active = true;`

After creating constraint make sure to activate it as perfectly pointed out by EmilioPelaez in comments:)

Comment: `view.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualTo(but.centerXAnchor).isActive = true` (or something similar, I wrote this out of my memory) would be a better way to do it.

Comment: @emiliopelaez : I agree :)

Comment: @yumyumyum : You getting any error on console buddy ??

Comment: @yumyumyum : hahahahaha :) I posted a swift code buddy url is objective C hence compilation error :) U need Objective-C code lemme post it :)

Comment: @yumyumyum : Gimme a minute :)

Comment: Please note in my POST, there is a full screen checkbox ticked.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24169315/ - while using your code i get this in the console.

Comment: Your code works. Man thanks a lot, its exactly pointed in the bottom center. now. i need your contact details from profile if i have Objective-C job i need to contact you man, genius!!!!

Comment: Updated the answer with mistakes in ur code which was causing console logs because of auto layout constraints breaks please have a look :) finally you can always contact me at https://www.linkedin.com/in/sandeep-bhandari-5b70b193/

Answer (score 0):

> Set to bottom center with auto layout

No.  You have set no constraints regarding the center of anything.

Comment: Your constraints are weird enough that I would expect an error message in the console! Why do you not mention it?